# Сортировка списка в заданном юзером порядке

Tags: java, сортировка, list

У меня есть список:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
```

На фротенде юзер напротив каждой строки проставил цифры, в каком порядке должен отсортироваться даный список.
Например:

```
"one" - 3;
"two" - 4;
"three" - 2;
"four" - 5;
"five" - 1;
```

В таком случаи мой список должен быть отсортирован так:

```
"five", "three", "one", "two", "four".
```

Как это можно реализовать в Java?

Comment: а что у вас не получается?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать HashMap, на место значения поставьте,строку "five" и т.д. , а на месте ключа, число 1 и т.д. , потом по ключам произвести сортировку в любую коллекцию, которую захотите, или смотря в каком виде к вам приходят данные, можно даже при окончании рассчётов , перед записью в коллекцию, но это уже зависит от вашей реализации

Comment: Если скажите в каком виде цифры на против каждой строки передаются, возможно,напишу еще варианты

Comment: Только не HashMap , а TreeMap, потому как HashMap  не гарантирует порядок элементов в коллекции в принципе и больше ничего делать не надо. TreeMap автоматически все отсортирует

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробую использовать TreeMap

Comment: Согласен с Gin Tasan, и насчет сортировки... сортировка– это  упорядочивание информации путем перестановки элементов в определенном порядке. Здесь же идет речь не о сортировке. В данном случае упорядочивания не происходит, а выполняется расстановка элементов согласно выбора пользователя (на фронте). Поэтому упорядочивание элементов в коллекциях это не тот случай. Необходимо определить заданную систему расстановки и требования к программе, из этого строить алгоритм.

Comment: Если юзер поставит два одинаковых ключа? "one" - 3;  "two" - 1;  "three" - 2;  "four" - 5;  "five" - 1;   Value с одинаковыми ключами надо отсортировать по алфавиту.  Что в этом случае лучше использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("one", 3);
    map.put("two", 4);
    map.put("three", 2);
    map.put("four", 5);
    map.put("five", 1);

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");

    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(map::get));
```

Comment: Если юзер поставит два одинаковых ключа? "one" - 3;  "two" - 1;  "three" - 2;  "four" - 5;  "five" - 1;   Value с одинаковыми ключами надо отсортировать по алфавиту.  Что в этом случае лучше использовать?

Comment: `list.sort(Comparator.<String, Integer>comparing(map::get).thenComparing(Function.identity()))`